# Mongodb nodejs driver not returning JSON data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm stuck on my GET Route endpoint to return a JSON array of data from MongoDB to my localhost:5000 server so I can then retrieve it axios for my front-end. So far my code only console logs out the doc on the server terminal in Visual Studio Code with the data I need for the front-end

Here's the server code for the GET route

```
app.get('/pets', function(req, res){
const resultArray = [];
client.connect(err => {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const cursor = db.collection('pet').find({});
iterateFunc = (doc,err) => {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        resultArray.push(doc);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(doc, null, 4));
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
    }
    }
        cursor.forEach(iterateFunc);
        client.close();
        res.send({pets: resultArray});

  });
```

Here's the front-end Reactjs code for the get route

```
import React, {
  Component
}
from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class ListPets extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pets: [],
      isLoaded: false,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getPets();
  };

  getPets = async() => {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/pets/');
    const pets = res.data;
    this.setState({
      isLoaded: true,
      pets: pets
    });
    console.log('Data has been received!');
    console.log(pets.data)
    return pets;
  }

  render() {
    console.log('State: ', this.state);
    const {
      isLoaded,
    } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div> Loading... </div>;
    } else {
      return (<div></div>);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what does data look like on front-end ? , I think, since data is logged correctly on the server (after stringifiying it), try calling `toArray()` after find() like this : 

db.collection('pet').find({}).toArray()

Comment: It's an empty array in the browser console  pets: [ ]

Comment: Hi [Joshua Lipscomb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9509208/joshua-lipscomb),
aren't you satified with my answer?
Have you checked the provided sandbox?
Let me know what's the problem to help you further

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just fine: the problem is with your database.
In the example in this working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflowcom-59825758-hm26r) I replaced your request with a request to 
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you close the connection and respond to the user before the cursor gets exhausted.

You need to terminate the connection and respond to the request after the cursor is exhausted [Refer to the Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/)

Here is a modified version of your code :

```
app.get('/pets', async function(req, res){
  try {
    let resultArray = [];


    const db = client.db(dbName);
    // this will return a promise and wait until it is fulfilled.
    resultArray = await db.collection('test-coll').find({}).toArray();

    client.close();
    console.log(' >>>> ',resultArray);
    res.send({pets: resultArray});
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log('ERROR', error);
    client.close();
    res.status(400).send('ERROR');

  }
}
```

Also you should (I don't know your case) keep database connection alive while the server is running, so you should move DB connection and closing it from the routes handlers.

**NOTE** :

`toArray()` will fetch the entire dataset. You can still use `cursor.forEach()` like this :

```
app.get('/pets', async function(req, res){
  try {
    const resultArray = [];
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const cursor = db.collection('test-coll').find({});

    const endCallBack = (e) => { // called when all docs are read
      client.close();
      console.log(' >>>> ',resultArray);
      res.send(resultArray)
    }
    const iterateFunc = (doc,err) => {
      if(err) {
        return console.log(err)
      }
      if (doc) {
        resultArray.push(doc);
      }
    }
    cursor.forEach(iterateFunc, endCallBack);
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log('ERROR', error);
    client.close();
    res.status(400).send('ERROR');
  }
}
```